# Fglrx AMD Catalyst 12.6 doesn't compile in Ubuntu 12.10 (64 bit or 32 bit)

Tags: ati, compiling, radeon, fglrx, catalyst

Ubuntu won't compile the AMD Catalyst driver package 12.6 from the AMD website. After package creation and during installation I see in `/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.970/build/make.log` there is an error during compiling. This really sucks because the Ubuntu repository `fglrx` package doesn't see my `Radeon HD3450`.  Here is the output of the logfile:

```
DKMS make.log for fglrx-8.970 for kernel 3.5.0-19-generic (i686)
Thu Dec 13 06:38:24 CST 2012
AMD kernel module generator version 2.1
doing Makefile based build for kernel 2.6.x and higher
rm -rf *.c *.h *.o *.ko *.a .??* *.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/3.5.0-19-generic/build SUBDIRS=/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.970/build/2.6.x modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-19-generic'
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.970/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.o
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.970/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.c: In function ‘KCL_MEM_AllocLinearAddrInterval’:
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.970/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.c:2152:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘do_mmap’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.970/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.970/build/2.6.x] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-19-generic'
make: *** [kmod_build] Error 2
build failed with return value 2
```

Oh well, back to Windows 7.

Comment: Well, you'll be having a hard time. I corrected the errors, but that won't do much. You can follow here:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/226396/acer-aspire-one-725-missing-graphic-card-driver-for-radeon-hd-6290

Answer (score 1):

Read [this link](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29) carefully and try again.

Follow these steps:

Install the prerequisite packages:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs dh-make dkms execstack dh-modaliases linux-headers-generic
```

If you are using the x86_64 architecture (64 bit):

```
sudo apt-get install lib32gcc1
```

Download the driver. This package contains both the 32-bit and 64-bit driver.

```
wget http://www2.ati.com/drivers/legacy/12-6/amd-driver-installer-12.6-legacy-x86.x86_64.zip
unzip amd-driver-installer-12.6-legacy-x86.x86_64.zip
chmod +x amd-driver-installer-12.6-legacy-x86.x86_64.run
```

Create and install

```
sudo sh ./amd-driver-installer-12.6-legacy-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/quantal
sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
```

then

```
sudo amdconfig --initial -f
```

After all this, if you can't login switch to a new tty using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and remove the `fglrx` driver using

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
```

Then to use the open source drivers

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
sudo rm -rf /etc/ati
```

If you receive

```
$ E: Internal Error, No file name for libgl1-mesa-dri
```

Change the third command above to:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 xserver-xorg-core
```

Comment: Thanks you for posting this. It solved all of my ubuntu gaming problems.